# includepdf overlays document stack on one page

Tags: latex, pdfpages

I'm trying to include a PDF in a document using `\includepdf`. The problem is that Latex is putting all sites of the pdf on one page of the document (over each other). I'm a bit lost on that one and didn't found any solutions.

```
\begin{figure}[H]

\includepdf[landscape,pages={1-6}]{Zeichnungen/Motor}

\label{Motor} 

\end{figure}
```

[image: image of what the PDF looks like]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `\includepdf`, don't put it in a figure environment.

If you do want to use the figure environment, use the good old `\inlcudegraphics`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pgffor}


\begin{document}

with pdfpages:

\includepdf[pages={1-6}]{example-image-duck}

\clearpage

with good old graphicx

\foreach \x in {1,...,6}{
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \includegraphics[page=\x]{example-image-duck}
  \label{Motor-\x}
\end{figure}
}

\end{document}
```